# True or False: $\|H\epsilon\|^2 \sim \chi^2_{p+1}$

Tags: regression, self-study, chi-squared-test

True or False: $\|H\epsilon\|^2 $~  $\chi^2_{p+1}
$
(H is that hat matrix and $\epsilon$~N(0,$\sigma^2I_n)$

My current strategy is letting $\epsilon=(I-H)$ so we have $\|H(I-H)\|^2$

Then, via idempotency of H, we get $\|H^2-H\|^2 = \|H-H\|^2 = 0$, which means this is false.

Is this correct? feels to good to be true.

I also have reasoning for why it could be true now:
Any linear combination of independent normal variables is normal. e is a normal random variable so it square is chi square with degrees of freedom 1. The hat matrix has p+1 columns though, so the combined degrees of freedom becomes p+1.

Is my First answer right or my second answer right?

Answer (score 1):

Since $H$ is a projection matrix of rank $p+1$ I think it directly follows that the qudratic form $||H\epsilon||^2 = \epsilon'H'H\epsilon$ follows the stated chi square distribution. I cannot make sense of what you say of equating $\epsilon$ (a random vector) to $I - H$ (a matrix).